# Querying a model based on user input in Django

Tags: python, django, web-applications

I am new to Django and I am trying to build a basic search/filter feature; for example, a basic version of the refine/filter part on amazon while searching for products. (I am using Sqlite3 in development)

I think I could implement a filter in which you could click part of a form and it would return a page with the database items that match the query, however, I am not sure on how I could do this if the search contained more than one part to the query, for example if the search was to find a book that was published before 2009 and costs more than £4.99, I am unsure on how to do this.

I am looking to build a checkbox type of filter rather than a search like google.

[This sort of filter/search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5TfT.png)

All help is appreciated, Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://django-filter.readthedocs.io

This is what you're looking for.